# Google Apps Script: How to set return to my page?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm using Google Apps Script to write values from a form to a Google Spreadsheet.

I have the form in my HTML page and its action calls the Google Apps Script to write in the sheet.

Now I'd like to go back to my site with a flag var and show a message (Error or Complete) based on the result of the function.

I know how to create and set the flag variable but I don't know how to "send" it to my page. I was only able to show my flag with something like this (that's the whole function I have in GAS)

```
function doPost(e){

var id = "";
var name = e.parameter['name'];
var surname = e.parameter['surname'];
var serial = e.parameter['serial'];
var eMail = e.parameter['email'];
var text = e.parameter['text'];
var date = new Date();
var ans = ""
var ctrl= "WIP";

var vals = [id, date, name, surname, serial, eMail, text, ans, flag];
var sheetObj =SpreadsheetApp.openById("myKey").getSheetByName('Requests').appendRow(vals);
return ContentService.createTextOutput(someOutput);
}
```

Someone knows how to do what I need?

Thanks a lot for your help!

S.

Comment: Is the form written with Google Apps Script and published as a web app?  If yes, when you send the data back to server side are you using `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(SuccessFunction).withFailureHandler(FailFunction).serverFunc(val);`  If yes, you would use the functions inside the () for the withSuccessHandler and withFailureHandler items to do the Succes and Failure messaging inside your client side script.

Comment: @Karl_S I updated the question and added the code of my script: I have my form in a HTML page. Its action calls the script on GAS. I have to came back from it to my page, and say "Everything's ok!"

Comment: When I do this I create the form in the GAS using the [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) and then publish the script as a web app and include the form in my page via an iframe.  This puts the entire form itself in the GAS and allows me to easily pass data back and forth including success/failures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

`return ContentService.createTextOutput("Complete").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);`

Or in case of exception return 'Error' from your `catch` block like this

`return ContentService.createTextOutput("Error").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This create the value and works perfectly, but I need that the script sends me back to the previous page with the parameter.
Long story short: I'm developping a webapp and I will turn it to a real one using PhoneGap or similar services. I need to send the form to a Google Spreadsheet (done) and, after that, come back to my webpages... I tried stuffs as using createTextOutput with a form in which the action send me to my page, but I need to do it dynamically in the easest way possible...